# Extract value from first column in pandas dataframe and add it in file name while saving

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe

```
year   city         population
2002   Chicago      100000
2002   Dallas       150000
2002   Denver       200000
```

I want to extract "2002" (One file will have same value in each row in first column) from first column and add it in file name I will save

Output file name -
2002_city_population.csv

I am trying this

```
df = pd.read_csv('city_population.csv', index_col=0)
df.to_csv('2002_city_population.csv')
```

Currently I am hardcoding "2002" in file name. But I want 2002 to come from first column of file as each file will have different year

Comment: Is that all you're doing, or is there additional processing involved? In other words, are you just trying to rename the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a variable and some f-string formatting.

```
year = df.at[0, 'year']

df.to_csv(f'{year}_city_population.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other years in your dataframe? If so, you could do this:

```py
for year, group in df.groupby("year"):
    group.to_csv(f"{year}_city_population.csv")
```